# I need to pass a file.txt to a string buffer

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have a .txt file that I want to pass to a buffer with this "file_to_buffer" function, but the terminal always show that the buffer is not initialized. I assume it's an error because of the malloc but I'm not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void file_to_buffer(char *file_name, char *buffer)
{
    FILE *file;
    int tam;
    
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (! file){
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", file_name);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (file){
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        tam = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc ((sizeof(char) * tam) + 1);
        if (buffer)
            fread(buffer, 1, tam, file);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

int main()
{
    char file_name[100]; 
    char *buffer;

    scanf("%s", file_name);

    file_to_buffer(file_name, buffer);

    puts(buffer);

    free(buffer);
}
```

When i do it outside the function, in the main, it works. I think i'm passing the value by copy and not by reference, but i don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: How about _returning_ the buffer instead `char *file_to_buffer(char *file_name)`?

Comment: Other problems: no _null character_ appended.   `ftell()` return `long`.  `(sizeof(char) * tam) + 1)` conceptually wrong.  Better as `sizeof(char) * ( tam + 1)`.  Never use `%s` without width  like `scanf("%99s", file_name);`.